Proving $A-B\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}(A-C_i)$
Suppose that $A,B,I$ are sets, and $C_i$ is a set for every $i\in I$. Suppose that $C_i\subseteq B$ for every $i\in I$. Show that: $$A-B\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}(A-C_i)$$
I am new to set theory and proofs so please keep that in mind while answering. Here is my attempt:
Let $x\in A-B\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}(A-C_i)$
It follows that: $x\in A- B \implies\forall_{i\in I}\; x\in A-C_i$
Meaning: $x\in A \land x\not\in B \implies\forall_{i\in I}\; x\in A\land x\not\in C_i$
Here I am stuck. I know I need to use my given statement of $C_i\subseteq B$ but I don't know how to implement this. I also know that this statement means all $x\in C_i\implies x\in B$ but I don't know how to fit this in with what I have so far. Can I use contrapositive and then prove a contradiction with the previous statement? Thank for the help

I don't really follow what you are trying to do. If you want to show $X\subseteq Y$, then you want to show that $x\in X$ implies $x\in Y$.
So, start with $x\in A-B$. Then, $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. You want to show that
$$x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}(A-C_i)$$
i.e., for every $i\in I$, $x\in A-C_i$. Can you show this?

Since I assume $x\in A-B$, does it follow that $x\not\in C$ because $C_i\subseteq B$?

@Grey: Exactly and you are done.
